# Reusable d3 charts with optional functionality

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I encapsulated d3 charts into function as suggested best practice from creator in blog [Towards Reusable Charts](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/). Is it possible to create optional functionalities on top of this chart, so calling specific function would trigger it, otherwise it would be omitted.

[Working JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9kxfpy4m/7/) (base working example from [Rob Moore's blog](https://www.toptal.com/d3-js/towards-reusable-d3-js-charts))

In JS line 56 I added a function which I'd like to create and then conditionally call in line 67.

My current way of doing it, is creating a boolean and setting it to `false` and then calling function with argument `true`. Problem of doing it this way is that the code gets too many conditionals and edge cases.

P.S. this question is not meant to be a discussion how to correctly apply axis to the chart. This is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to add additional functionalities after the chart is drawn

```
var runningChart = barChart().barPadding(2).fillColor('coral');

d3.select('#runningHistory')
        .datum(milesRun)
        .call(runningChart);
        
runningChart.x_axis(); // additional functionality
```

So that the original chart container can be saved in a variable and it can be used to append other functionalities. For example

```
function barChart() {
  var charContainer;

    function chart(selection){

        charContainer = d3.select(this).append('svg')
                .attr('height', height)
                .attr('width', width);

    }

  chart.x_axis = function() {
     // Add scales to axis
    var x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
               .scale(widthScale);
    charContainer.append('g').call(x_axis);
    return chart;
  }
}
```

If there is any need to add additional functionality before the chart is drawn, then all the functionalities can be saved in a Javascript object and drawn like in this example. https://jsfiddle.net/10f7hdae/